# How can a Vim syntax rule be constructed for multi-line string highlighting?

Tags: json, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I've got an "Annotated JSON" vim syntax file that supports a number of features such as comments. These JSON files are put through a pre-processor to either filter out idioms or to transform the annotated JSON file into a standard JSON file.

I'm now looking to add multiline strings to be supported in these files.  The syntax of a multiline string in the annotated JSON file is:

```
"""string that
spans over
multiple lines"""
```

The above is pre-processed to generate:

```
"string that\nspans over\nmultiple lines"
```

The triple-quote idiom can be escaped with an initial backslash:

```
"This is not a \"""multiline\""" string"
```

The above is pre-processed to generate:

```
"This is not a \"\"\"multiline\"\"\" string"
```

My problem is in defining the appropriate vim syntax so that the Annotated JSON file has nice formatting. Here's what I have so far:

```
syn match jsonMultilineStringMatch /"""\(.*\)"""/ contains=jsonMultilineString
syn region jsonMultilineString start=/"""/ end=/"""/
hi jsonMultilineString ctermfg=26 ctermbg=195 term=NONE cterm=NONE
```

I also commented out the line in the `json.vim` file:

```
"syn match   jsonTripleQuotesError  /"""/
```

My json.vim modification is rather crude and doesn't support escaping. I don't understand the vim idioms such as `\ze`, `concealends`, `contained`, and others I see in .vim files. And, the highlighting above includes the quotes themselves which is not consistent with how plain quotes are already being highlighted.

Can anyone suggest how I might improve the vim syntax and highlighting so that only the body of the multi-line quote is highlighted along with support for escapes, and done in a non-greedy way?

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that I messed around with this for a bit and could not for the life of me get just the body to highlight without sparking some quirky side-effects (discouraging, I know). You can, however, use the `skip=/\\"""/` setting with vim-syntax regions to ignore the escapes. To get this to work seamlessly, I would probably look to see if the original syntax file has a `cluster` of escapes that it is using to generalize the `skip` setting and try and manually add the escape to that cluster. Sorry, that's the best I've got. Hope it helps.

Comment: @BryanBugyi I'll try it out... thanks for your efforts!